# Wordpress - PHP Fatal Error - functions.php - while trying to get to wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, nginx, php, w3-total-cache

I have W3TC, Nginx, varnish and php5-fpm installed on an Ubuntu 12.04 image with 768 MB RAM.  The site itself is functioning fine, but when I try to access /wp-admin I get an HTTP 500 Internal Server error.

I have went to the logs and have looked and found the following error:

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes
>   exhausted (tried to allocate 5184285 bytes) in
>   /var/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 251 while reading response
>   header from upstream

I have seen many posts where it says to make the following settings:

> Increase your allocated memory in wp-config.php or wherever you need
>   it:
>
> define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
>
> In case PHP itself is running out of
>   memory, you can increase that by modifying php.ini and restarting your
>   web server.
>
> memory_limit 256M

But haven't had any luck.  I have also restored the image from a previous backup and the issue still exists.  No plugins have been modified or updated since the previous time I was able to access the backend.

I also turned WP_DEBUG to true and saw this:

> Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles
>   should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts ,
>   admin_enqueue_scripts , or init hooks. Please see Debugging in
>   WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version
>   3.3.) in /var/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2758 Notice: wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not
>   be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts ,
>   admin_enqueue_scripts , or init hooks. Please see Debugging in
>   WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version
>   3.3.) in /var/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2758 Notice: Undefined variable: paged in
>   /var/www/wp-content/themes/organic_magazine/functions.php on line 419

Comment: Please deactivate all plugin at once and then check is it working or not?

Comment: how do you deactivate them all at once?

Comment: i mean deactivate all plugin one by one and then check

Comment: Ok.  I found a plugin that went bad on me.  Thanks for your assistance.  Please post below and I will accept your answer.